# Why is the Java 7 runtime inconsistent with the Java 7 documentation for subpackages of java.nio?

Tags: java-7, java.nio.file

I'm encountering multiple inconsistencies between the Java 7 runtime library and the Java 7 documentation for subpackages of java.nio on my Linux workstation. For example, the class

```
$ jar tf /usr/java/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/rt.jar | fgrep java/nio/file/attribute/Attributes
java/nio/file/attribute/Attributes.class
```

Doesn't even exist in what I believe is the official documentation, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/.

Does anyone know why these discrepancies exist and/or a workaround?

Comment: I suspect that `Attributes` is a non-public class, and therefore will not appear in the public API.

Comment: skaffman, The class is public; I can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you the runtime version that you have is not a final one, though you are reviewing the documentation of the stable java 7 version.

Here's the documentation for that class:
http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b124/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/Attributes.html

As you can notice it's for the version 7 build 124, and it states there at the top:

> Please note that the specifications and other information contained
>   herein are not final and are subject to change. The information is
>   being made available to you solely for purpose of evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a prerelase of Java 7 JDK installed on your machine, the final releases do not have that class anymore.
You can download and install the current release directly from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

PS
Hints:

- remember to download the version suitable for you Linux installation: 32 or 64 bit
- I had good results with both installation types, rpm and tar.gz, although I prefer the latter one for fast experiments with multiple JDKs.

Comment: Victor, the 1.7.0 release might be old, but it isn't an early-access release. If you're right, then the 1.7 API was changed after 1.7.0 -- which I would find surprising.

Comment: Steve, I didn't say 1.7.0 is old, in fact it is the latest version. If you query the version ("java -version" or "javac -version"), what is the version string?

I did a Google search, and the first hit was
http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b125/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/class-use/Attributes.html
as Nitzan already pointed out,

Comment: Steve, I didn't say 1.7.0 is old, in fact it is the latest version. If you query the version ("java -version" or "javac -version"), what is the exact version string?

I have several JDK7 versions installed (e.g. Linux 1.7.0_03, Win32&64bit 1.7.0_01), and they do not have the class "java.nio.file.attribute.Attributes". I did a Google search for this class, and already the first hit points to a **"Java™ Platform Standard Ed. 7 DRAFT ea-b125"** page. As Nitzan already pointed out (his link points to b124), that page is from a prerelease version of 1.7.0.